# Array of integer in SNMP

Tags: snmp, mib

I want my custom SNMP agent to expose some metrics.
But I don't know how to deal with arrays of simple types (byte, int, double).

How can I write a MIB file to expose array of int ?

Is there a simpler way than the tables/entries/columns/indexes route ?

Comment: The actual meaning of the integers can help you make the decision, which you simply forgot to put as part of the question.

Comment: The software is a gateway between Modbus and Snmp protocols. Modbus exposes registers (byte, word, dword...) by address i.e: read n bytes at offset x. I would like snmp users to query these data. The actual meaning of the data, the number and length of arrays depend on the modbus devices. For instance, they can come from building automation, scada... (temperatures, counters, valves control, etc..)